# How to enable/disable webcam by script (Win 10)

Tags: windows, webcam

I'm using for win 10 on my laptop and sometimes I need ti enable/disable my build in webcam and mic by any script or .exe file. 
In other words I need to switch this one by script:
[WebCam Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVDak.png)
I tried to find something in Google, but without success. Tell me where to start?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable and enable your webcam using PowerShell script.

1. List all your cameras:

   ```
   Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName *webcam*
   ```
2. Filter camera by status:

   ```
   Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName *webcam*  -Status OK
   ```
3. Disable the camera:

   ```
   Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId (Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName *webcam*  -Status OK).InstanceId
   ```
4. Enable the camera:

   ```
   Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId (Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName *webcam*  -Status Error).InstanceId
   ```

[image]

Comment: add   -Confirm:$false   can disable the confirmation prompt

Comment: Is there a canonical way to identify a camera device? My "Integrated Camera" and "Razer Kiyo" both have Class = Camera, but my "HD Pro Webcam C920" has Class = MEDIA. As you can tell from the friendly names, searching for FriendlyName = *cam* won't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmmh... it works if you are not using the webcam, but if it is still active it shows this error (running the powershell script as administrator):

> Disable-PnpDevice : Generic failure

> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId (Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "USB Video ...
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified:
>   ```
>
> (Win32_PnPEntity...7&169FD4E3&...):ROOT\cimv2\Win32_PnPEntity) [Disable-PnpDevice], > CimException
>
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041001,Disable-PnpDevice

- Is there any way to turn it off while it's still in use ? My problem is that after I end a Microsoft Teams meeting, I see that the cam is still in use, because I see its led still ON...